# Changing CSS on scroll and impact on Accessibility

Tags: css, position, accessibility, margin, breadcrumbs

I've breadcrumbs which will be aligned in the center by default(using margin: auto on container) as shown in 'default-breadcrumbs.jpg'.
[image]

Now, on scroll, I'm changing that to full screen width(by setting margin:0 on container) and making them fixed.

[image]

Since, the order of the breadcrumb steps remain the same, does it still affect accessibility? If yes, then how does it affect?

Answer (score 0):

From what you have written I think you are not doing any change which should have an impact on the accessibility and it should be not affected at all.

Comment: I think it is improved because the font-size is larger, so it's more readable

Comment: OK from this point of view, yeah it is even better. However, I am not sure if the picture is not just zoomed. If not then yeah, it is more readable.